# Flex lists not wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a seemingly simply requirement, a list `<ul />` of items `<div />`s of a fixed size. The items in the list should layout from left to right filling the available space before wrapping onto the next line.

Here is the basic HTML

```
<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex">
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  ......
</ul>
```

The class `.d-flex` is simply:

```
.d-flex {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

and the class `.list-box` just controls the sizing of the boxes.

What happens is the boxes are laid out in a single row from left to right, if there are too many boxes for the screen width the `<ul />` gains a horizontal scroll bar.

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/JohnRayson/pen/LmvQRQ):

```css
.list-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1>Bootstrap 4 Flex List</h1>
<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex">
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why don't the `<li />`s wrap?

Comment: Explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `flex-wrap` class with `d-flex`. [codepen](https://codepen.io/arpanpatel/pen/BxErNK)

```
<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap">
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  ......
</ul>
```

**About Flex wrap**

> The CSS flex-wrap property specifies whether flex items are forced
>   into a single line or can be wrapped onto multiple lines. If wrapping
>   is allowed, this property also enables you to control the direction in
>   which lines are stacked.

Comment: It would be good to add that the `flex-wrap` *class* is [defined by Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/scss/utilities/_flex.scss#L16) and that it sets the `flex-wrap` *property* to a value of `wrap`. It would also be good to indicate who you are quoting.

Comment: look at code i am using `flex-wrap` class by bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, knew it would be somthing simple... heres a fork with the additional class: https://codepen.io/JohnRayson/pen/KRYoXZ

Comment: sorry @Justastudent.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that by default, items in a flexbox layout will not wrap. The [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) property defaults to a value of `nowrap`. Setting it to `wrap` will make the items wrap as you intend to.

```css
.d-flex {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* add this */
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can get rid of the flexbox layout altogether. Just set the list items to [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) as `inline-block`. They will be placed one after another and wrap to new lines as necessary.

```css
.my-list {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.my-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.list-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h1><strike>Bootstrap 4 Flex</strike> List</h1>
<ul class="my-list">
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
  <li><div class="list-box"></div></li>
</ul>
```

[That's good old CSS 2 stuff.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) You don't even need Bootstrap.